# Angular 2.3.1 issue when compiling after upgrade (possible router issue?)

Tags: angular

After migrating an old angular2 project running on angular ~2.1.0 and angular-cli 1.0.0-beta.18 to a slightly newer version of angular and angular-cli (@angular/cli-beta.30 and angular 2.3.1) I am not able anymore to build the project (ng serve). I get the following error message:

```
ERROR in TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of null
    at Function.RouteDef.fromString (/Users/mariusstein/Projects/Supernova.Crm/Supernova.Crm/Client/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:33:26)
    at Object.listLazyRoutesOfModule (/Users/mariusstein/Projects/Supernova.Crm/Supernova.Crm/Client/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_impl.js:45:34)
    at Function.NgTools_InternalApi_NG_2.listLazyRoutes (/Users/mariusstein/Projects/Supernova.Crm/Supernova.Crm/Client/node_modules/@angular/compiler-cli/src/ngtools_api.js:74:39)
    at AotPlugin._getLazyRoutesFromNgtools (/Users/mariusstein/Projects/Supernova.Crm/Supernova.Crm/Client/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:240:66)
    at _donePromise.Promise.resolve.then.then.then.then.then (/Users/mariusstein/Projects/Supernova.Crm/Supernova.Crm/Client/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/plugin.js:493:24)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:103:7)

webpack: Failed to compile.
```

When forcing ng to recompile by making changes to a file, the compilation succeeds, however no sites are displayed only a blank white page.

Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

here my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --env=prod",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/material": "^2.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.33",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@vaadin/angular2-polymer": "^1.0.0-beta5",
    "angular2-datatable": "^0.5.1",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.0.0-beta.rc.1",
    "bootstrap": "4.0.0-alpha.4",
    "chart.js": "^2.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "glyphicons-halflings": "1.9.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "jquery": "^2.2.4",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.1.0",
    "lodash": "^4.16.6",
    "moment": "^2.15.2",
    "ng2-charts": "^1.4.1",
    "ng2-toastr": "^1.3.0",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-rc.4",
    "signalr": "^2.2.1",
    "tether": "^1.3.7",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.8"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.50",
    "@types/moment": "^2.13.0",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "@types/selenium-webdriver": "2.53.34",
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-beta.30",
    "codelyzer": "1.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

EDIT 1: Routing

```
import { ImeiActionListPrettyComponent } from './components/imei-action-list-pretty/imei-action-list-pretty.component';
import { ImeiEntryTableAdminComponent } from './components/imei-entry-table-admin/imei-entry-table-admin.component';
import { DashboardTraderComponent } from './components/dashboard-trader/dashboard-trader.component';
import { TraderUserListComponent } from './components/trader-user-list/trader-user-list.component';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth-guard.service';

import { MainLayoutComponent } from './components/main-layout/main-layout.component';

import { DashboardComponent } from './components/dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/login/login.component';
import { LoginLandingpageComponent } from './components/login-landingpage/login-landingpage.component';
import { TraderComponent } from './components/trader/trader.component';
import { ImportComponent } from './components/import/import.component';
import { TraderDetailsComponent } from './components/trader-details/trader-details.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './components/account/account.component';
import { AccountDetailsComponent } from './components/account-details/account-details.component';
import { MkzComponent } from './components/mkz/mkz.component';
import { TransactionsNotTraderRelatedComponent } from './components/transactions-not-trader-related/transactions-not-trader-related.component';
import { DeviceConfigComponent } from './components/device-config/device-config.component';
import { ImeiActionListComponent } from './components/imei-action-list/imei-action-list.component';
import { ImeiActionEditComponent } from './components/imei-action-edit/imei-action-edit.component';
import { TraderUserEditComponent } from './components/trader-user-edit/trader-user-edit.component';
import { AuthGuardAdminService } from './services/auth-guard-admin.service';
import { ImeiEntryCreationComponent } from './components/imei-entry-creation/imei-entry-creation.component';
import { ImeiEntryTableComponent } from './components/imei-entry-table/imei-entry-table.component';
import { TraderPartnerListComponent } from './components/trader-partner-list/trader-partner-list.component';
import { TraderPartnerEditComponent } from './components/trader-partner-edit/trader-partner-edit.component';
import { ImeiActionDetailsComponent } from './components/imei-action-details/imei-action-details.component';
import { LogoutComponent } from './components/logout/logout.component';
import { ImeiDeviceResolveService } from './services/imei-device-resolve.service';
import { ImeiActionRuleResolveService } from './services/imei-action-rule-resolve.service';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login-old',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginLandingpageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'logout',
    component: LogoutComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'forgotpw/:email/:key',
    component: LoginLandingpageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'landing/:partnerId',
    component: LoginLandingpageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'landing',
    component: LoginLandingpageComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'app',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardAdminService],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'trader',
        component: TraderComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'provider',
        component: TransactionsNotTraderRelatedComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'import',
        component: ImportComponent
      }, {
        path: 'trader-details/:traderId',
        component: TraderDetailsComponent
      }, {
        path: 'account',
        component: AccountComponent
      }, {
        path: 'account-details/:accountId',
        component: AccountDetailsComponent
      }, {
        path: 'mkz',
        component: MkzComponent
      }, {
        path: 'config/devices',
        component: DeviceConfigComponent,
        resolve: {
          devices: ImeiDeviceResolveService
        }
      }, {
        path: 'actions',
        component: ImeiActionListComponent
      }, {
        path: 'actions/edit/:actionId',
        component: ImeiActionEditComponent,
        resolve: {
          rules: ImeiActionRuleResolveService
        }
      }, {
        path: 'trader-user',
        component: TraderUserListComponent
      }, {
        path: 'trader-user/edit/:traderUserId',
        component: TraderUserEditComponent
      }, {
        path: 'trader-partner',
        component: TraderPartnerListComponent
      }, {
        path: 'trader-partner/edit/:traderPartnerId',
        component: TraderPartnerEditComponent
      }, {
        path: 'imei',
        component: ImeiEntryTableAdminComponent
      }
    ]
  }, {
    path: 'trader',
    component: MainLayoutComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardTraderComponent
      }, {
        path: 'actions',
        component: ImeiActionListPrettyComponent
      }, {
        path: 'actions/:actionId',
        component: ImeiActionDetailsComponent
      }, {
        path: 'my-imeis',
        component: ImeiEntryTableComponent
      }, {
        path: 'new-imei',
        component: ImeiEntryCreationComponent
      }
    ]
  }, {
    path: '**',
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    redirectTo: '/app/dashboard',
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  providers: []
})
export class RoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Lazy loaded modules. Probably bad module string.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, can you please elaborate? What do you mean by bad module string?

Comment: You got `loadChild` in your routing. It points to module that should be loaded. It is probably wrong.

Comment: I update my question with the routing definition. I don't use loadChild there (however, I do define child routes). When you say module, do you mean component or do I have the wrong idea here?

Comment: Ah so you are not using lazy loaded modules. hmm